# Android AlarmManager after app was closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I was working on something an alarm, and the user should set a time at when I'll post a notification to notice the user to do something everyday, so i did these piece of code:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,timeAhead,1000*60*60*24,pendingIntent);
```

The problem is that when the user close the application via TaskManager or something alike, the pending intent did not get invoked, i was wonder how to get the alarm event when my application was closed therefore I can restart my app and do my remaining logic, since the system alarm app can do something like that I think there should be a solution for this.